# Convert txt file, with variable categories, to dictionary and pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I've converted a txt file that has a fixed number of variables, for every entry, to a dict and df.  For example, if every entry in the txt file has a Date entry followed by Category A, Category B, and Category C, it has a set number of variables.  In my current question, there are many categories but most are empty (NaN). I don't want to carry the null value category entries in the txt file.  In this case, the txt file may have one Date entry with only Category A and Category C, and another Date entry with only Category B.  In the final df, each date is a row and some columns of that row are NaN.  My problem is reading that txt file, with unlisted categories in some entries, produces a "All arrays must be of the same length" error.

For example, I've read this txt file:

```
Date: Jan 1
Cat A: 5
Cat B: 8
Cat C:  2

Date: Feb 6
Cat A: 7
Cat B: 2
Cat C: 3

etc...for multiple dates.

with open ('text.txt', "r") as file:
    df = file.read()

date = re.findall('Date:(.*?)\n', df)
col_a = re.findall('Cat A:(.*?)\n', df)
col_b = re.findall('Cat B:(.*?)\n', df)
col_c = re.findall('Cat C:(.*?)\n', df)

dic = {'Date':date, 'Col A': col_a, 'Col B': col_b, 'Col C': col_c}
```

This works fine when the txt file always contains Cat A, B, & C.  In another case, I have many categories, and the text file would be unnecessarily messy to carry them all when there is no entry.  I want to read this txt:

```
Date: Jan 1
Cat A: 1
Cat F: 5

Date: Jan 10
Cat F: 6

Date: Dec 5
Cat A: 8
Cat B: 5
Cat E: 7
Cat F: 1
```

In the final df, each row can have Nan values where the cat wasn't in the entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the text file you provide, here is one way to to it:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Import and order data
df = pd.read_table("file.txt", sep=":", header=None).pivot(columns=0, values=1)

# Deal with NA values
df["Date"] = df["Date"].fillna(method="ffill")
for date in df["Date"].unique():
    df.loc[df["Date"] == date, :] = (
        df.loc[df["Date"] == date, :].fillna(method="ffill").fillna(method="bfill")
    )

# Cleanup
df = (
    df.drop_duplicates()
    .pipe(
        lambda df_: df_.reindex(
            columns=["Date"] + [col for col in df_.columns if col != "Date"]
        )
    )
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
df.columns.name = ""
```

```py
print(df)
# Output
      Date Cat A Cat B Cat E Cat F
0    Jan 1     1   NaN   NaN     5
1   Jan 10   NaN   NaN   NaN     6
2    Dec 5     8     5     7     1
```

Comment: Hi @Laurent, Thanks for your help.  The .pivot() on the read and the ffill on Date, opened ideas.  Using groupby("Date") at that point quickly consolidates the table.  Thanks for taking the time to play with this and offer an idea.  I'm using this method as a simple means to track expenses in NotePad.